# Consultar, comparar y concatenar valores múltiples de dos tablas

Tags: php, html, array

Existen 2 tablas, requiero obtener varios valores guardados en un solo campo(son id) de la tabla document, una vez que los tengo los comparo con otra tabla(project) para traer los valores de los nombres y los concateno.

```js
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from document where project_id in (".$project_id.
  ")");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
  $array = $row['project_id'];
  $array1 = explode(',', $array);

  $code = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM project WHERE id = $array1");

  if ($code != '') {
    $project = '';
    foreach($code["name"] as $row) {
      $project. = $row.
      ', ';
    }
    $project = substr($project, 0, -2);
  }
}
```

Muestra los siguientes errores o warning:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que `explode` te devuelve un array.  Debes iterar los elementos del array y generar una consulta para cada valor asi:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from document where project_id in (".$project_id.
  ")");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
  $array = $row['project_id'];
  $array1 = explode(',', $array);

  foreach($array1 as $id) {
    $code = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM project WHERE id = $id");
    $project = '';
    while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($code)) {
        $project. = $row1['name'].
        ', ';
    }
    $project = substr($project, 0, -2);        
  }
}
```

Comment: Me da este error: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in C:\wamp64\www\SysCPC\ajax\documents.php on line 140

Comment: ya edite, intentalo asi

Comment: No da error, pero de los dos valores ejemplo campo 3, 4 me muestra solo uno

Comment: intenta mover la variable `$project` fuera del `foreach`